# How do I remote into my current windows session in Unity on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I seem to be able to remote into xwindows using a new session in Gnome or Xfce but I don't seem to be able to remote into my current session using Unity (using VNC).

Is there a way to do this, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install x11vnc

```
sudo apt install x11vnc
```

When you run it it will not create a new X11 session but use the existing one.

To connect to the display :0 you need to connect to port 5900.